# How to get the value which is after the point

Tags: java, android, string, double, decimal

How to get the value which is after the point.

Example: 
If 5.4 is the value and I want to get the value 4 not 0.4, how can I do this?

Comment: Please dont use string operations, they are very slow

Comment: wow i'm deeply surprised that **no** answer uses the % (modulo) operator ?!?!?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use String functions for that :

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Double d = 5.14;
    String afterD = String.valueOf(d);
    afterD =afterD.substring(afterD.indexOf(".") + 1);
    System.out.println(afterD);
}
```

1. first of all convert number to String,
2. Then using Substring get `indexof(".") + 1` then print it.

& see it ll work.

OR You can try :

```
 double d = 4.24;
 BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(( d - Math.floor( d )) * 100 );
 bd = bd.setScale(4,RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
 System.out.println( bd.intValue() );
```

will print : `24`

suppose your input is `4.241` then you have to add 1 extra `0` in `BigDecimal` bd formula i.e. instead of `100` it ll be `1000`.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**:

```
  double i = 5.4;
  String[] s = Double.toString(i).split("\\.");
  System.out.println(s[1]);
```

**output**:

```
4
```

**Explantion**:

you can convert the double to String type and after that use split function which split the converted double to String in two pieces because of  using `\\.` delimiter. At the end, type out the second portion that you want.

you can try this

code:

```
double i = 4.4;
  String s = Double.toString(i);
  boolean seenFloatingPoint = false;

    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
        if(s.charAt(j)== '.' && !seenFloatingPoint){
            seenFloatingPoint = true;
        } else if (seenFloatingPoint)
            System.out.print(s.charAt(j));
    }
        System.out.println("");
```

output:

```
  4
```

Comment: @Wiz25 you are welcome I posted another solution so If you wanna take a look at it plz :)

Answer (score 0):

the one line answer is

```
int floatingpoint(float floating){

    return Integer.valueOf((Float.toString(floating).split(".")[1]));



}
```

which will do as follows:

1. convert the number e.g 56.45 to string
2. then split the string in string array where [0]="56" and [1]="45"
3. then it will convert the the second string into integer.

Thanks.

Comment: In java float values are initialised with the post fix f, for ex `5.14f`, otherwise it is considered as double value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
Double d = 5.14;
        String afterD = String.valueOf(d);
        String fractionPart = afterD.split("\\.")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i=(int)yourvalue;
float/double afterDecimal= yourvalue - i;
int finalValue = afterDecimal * precision;//define precision as power of 10

EX. yourvalue = 2.345; 
int i=(int)yourvalue;//i=2 
float/double afterDecimal= yourvalue - i;//afterDecimal=0.345 
int finalValue = afterDecimal * precision;
//finalValue=0.345*10 or 
//finalValue=0.345*100 or
// finalValue=0.345*1000
```

...

Comment: Please dont use string operations, they are very slow

Comment: how do i get precision value??

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
double d = 5.24;

int i = Integer.parseInt(Double.toString(d).split("\\.")[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println((int)(5.4%((int)5.4)*10));`

Basically `5.4 mod 5` gets you `.4 * 10` gets you `4`.